# Call a specific array in a JSON API call

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I'm trying to call the API but it doesn't return me anything.
I'm calling it like: `res.on('data', d => { const RetrieveFromApi = JSON.parse(d).FLUX.quote.USD.price;`.

The API is successfully called since I can see it in the API history, and data is defined as `d`.

[image: API Call]

Can you help me please?

Comment: What gives you `console.log(JSON.parse(d))` ?

Comment: There you go :) [Screen of the logs](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/434487697646551040/903021927935922216/unknown.png)

Comment: @newcomerindev it your screenshot of the log shows that the object has a `status` field - same as the screenshot of your question. Therefore `d` doesn't contain `data` as you claim in your question. Seems you just need `JSON.parse(d).FLUX.quote.USD.price` -> `JSON.parse(d).data.FLUX.quote.USD.price`

Comment: I still have the same error, here is the logs : [Logs](https://prnt.sc/1xj4184)

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part that says, "**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question."

Answer (score 0):

from your screen provided in comment, you passed one property you don't access to it which is `data`
So just add *property `data`* before `FLUX`

```js
JSON.parse(d).FLUX.quote.USD.price;
             ^data.FLUX.quote.USD.price;
```

Comment: I still have the same error, here is the logs : [Logs](https://prnt.sc/1xj4184)

Comment: the log seems not working !

Comment: Yeah, that's why I'm trying to find some help lol

Answer (score 0):

From the image of the log the object seems incomplete at the end, did you try to use JSON.stringify(d) to see if there are any errors on the json object? or copy the response on https://jsonlint.com to check?

Because the error message points that the parse doesn't find a valid json object, maybe that is the whole point.

And the other tip is to try to store the value of JSON.parse in an variable before trying to access his values.